# I'm trying to run a Python script to restore broken links in my Google Chrome session

Tags: python, json, package, command

I'm trying to run this script called "Great Suspender Restore URLS" in order to, well, restore the broken Great Suspender links to my tabs from my Google Chrome session, the windows of which have been exported into a JSON file.  Now, the instructions from GitHub appear to be quite simple, & I was successfully able to download & install the Great Suspender Restore URLs Python package, but I have had NO luck getting the actual script to work so that my links can actually be restored.

I tried fixing the environment variables by adding a user path to the folder where Python itself is located, but the Python terminal gives me "Invalid Syntax".  I have the list of tabs located in the "Great Suspender Restore URLs" subfolder in 'Python -- Scripts', & I try to run the script that I need to fix said list, but it's not working.  I don't know how to type in the path where the GSRU script is, & I still don't have any luck when I try out path-&-file input methods mentioned on other websites.  And I'm certain there's several other methods I tried, but I can't remember any of them -- that's how long I've been running myself ragged trying to run this one simple script!  Here's some illustrative screencaps that should elucidate my troubles pertaining to what I'm trying to accomplish.

[The script I want to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTtQp.png)

[Where my tabs JSON file is located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6M1u.png)

[Where I copied the "Great Suspender Restore URLs" files to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqblH.png)

[Where I copied the JSON tabs list to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXzed.png)

[Getting the invalid syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okRZB.png)

I'll probably add a few more screenshots later, so keep an eye out.

Comment: BTW, I spaced the pictures & descriptions apart, so it would be easier to see.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run Command Prompt command line in Python.  Python only executes python statements.  The `>>>` prompts are the default 'enter a python statement' prompts.  Open a Command Prompt window.  You should see a prompt something like `C:\Users\Terry>`.  Enter `pip install ...` there.